# What is a good library for horizontally concatenating text using Java?

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I have two strings

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
```

and

```
BBB
BBB
BBB
```

What I'm looking for is a method `String concatenateHorizontally(String left, String right, String separator, options...)` that I can pass those strings to and receive a String

```
AAA BBB
AAA BBB
AAA BBB
```

I do this a lot in Vim (using blockwise visual mode) but couldn't find a library that allows to do it in Java code. I'm aware that for simple examples this is trivial to implement but I was hoping that someone  has already solved this in a more generic way (e.g. with options to decide whether to replace or append, to insert at a fixed position or the line end, handling different newline characters, correct Unicode behavior etc.).

Can someone point me to such a library for horizontally concatenating text?

Comment: This function seems so niche, I think it'll be hard to find a specific library that has this included. I know the task of making your own might seem tedious, but aren't you being just a bit lazy? :P

Comment: It's not the tedium I'm trying to avoid but the reinvention of a wheel that someone might have already solved for a large variety of wheels. Many text editors offer this behavior, so I was guessing that text manipulation like this is bundled in some library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(concatenateHorizontally("AAA\nBBB\nCCC", "111\n222\n333", "\n", " "));
        System.out.println(concatenateHorizontally("AAA\nBBB", "111\n222\n333", "\n", " "));
        System.out.println(concatenateHorizontally("AAA\nBBB\nCCC", "111\n222", "\n", " "));
    }

    private static String concatenateHorizontally(final String left, final String right, String br, String concat)
    {
        {

            String[] lefts = left.split(br);
            String[] rights = right.split(br);
            int max = Math.max(lefts.length, rights.length);

            StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {

                if (i < lefts.length)
                    sB.append(lefts[i]).append(concat);

                if (i < rights.length)
                    sB.append(rights[i]);

                sB.append(br);
            }

            return sB.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but again, I wasn't looking for the algorithm but for a library that was more versatile. But since this is the best algorithm proposed (will basically work for strings of different line counts though it will trim the shorter string and not align them), I'm going to accept it. Thanks for your input Franz Ebner, user3313050 and tassaert.l.

Answer (score 3):

You can split by line returns and append alternately.

*No code example because of "Easy Kill".*

**EDIT :**

Implemented because of "Nice":

```
String concatenateHorizontally(final String left, final String right) {

    String br = "\n";

    String[] lefts = left.split(br);
    String[] rights = right.split(br);

    if(lefts.length!=rights.length)
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This is where my time becomes money");

    StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < lefts.length; i++) {

        sB.append(lefts[i]);
        sB.append(rights[i]);
        sB.append(br);
    }

    return sB.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm doing right now, yes. Your code will break if `left` has more lines than `right`. If `right` has more lines than `left`, not all of `right` is concatenated.

Comment: StackOverflow is about 'give me a hint' and not 'implement my interface for me, including all possibilities'...

Comment: That's why I asked for a hint on libraries that implement behavior beyond the trivial.

Comment: Here, have an upvote for taking the time to actually make it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
   class m
   {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
   String s="AAA"+"\n"+
            "AAA"+"\n"+
            "AAA"+"\n";
   String s1="BBB"+"\n"+
             "BBB"+"\n"+
             "BBB"+"\n";

  String[] gets=s.split("\n");
  String[] gets1=s1.split("\n");
  String concate="";
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    concate=concate+gets[i]+"\t"+gets1[i]+"\n"; 
   }
  System.out.print(concate);           
 }    
}
```

output:

```
     AAA BBB
     AAA BBB
     AAA BBB
```

Comment: Yes, that is trivial implementation I mentioned (that's what I'm doing now). But what if I wanted to extend the behavior not to concatenate the lines at the line end but insert the `right` part at a fixed position?

Comment: @kba If you want the right part at a fixed positon, you probably want to use spaces instead of a tab separating the two parts. In that case calculate the amount of spaces to add (wanted position minus length of left string) and concatenate that amount of spaces before concatenating the right part.

Comment: @tassaert.l Right, one also has to calculate spaces if the two strings have a different number of lines.